# how to fix 'Call to undefined method PhpParser\Node\Expr\Variable::toString()' from goaop framework

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, codeception

I am working on some tests and periodically, all tests start to fail.
I get this error when i call a class 'PaymentHistory' which extends a model.
The code works without a problem so im thinking the error lies in the test, maybe it's the way i've set it up with codeception.

Reinstalled all vendor files,
changed some settings from aspectmock

```
$pmh = new \App\DAO\PaymentHistory();
Test::double('PaymentHistory', ['find' => $pmh]);
$payment = new Payment();
$payment->get($wcontext, 1);//$wcontext is created higher in this function

public function get(WContext $context, $paymentId): WPaymentTransaction
{
    //todo handle this if owner dowsn not own payment
    $payment = PaymentHistory::find($paymentId);
    return $this->generateWPaymentTransactionDB($payment);
}
```

The function should, instead of reaching the database, return an empty object as stated with `'Test::double('PaymentHistory', ['find' => $pmh])'` 
but returns `call to undefined method PhpParser\Node\Expr\Variable::toString()`

Comment: for now the problem has fixed itself

Comment: it came back some time ago, for people finding this. in the end it was incompatible with goaop framework or something like that. never got to really test it since it disappeared by itself. error came up after a composer update